# Time Machine drive doesn't mount; exit code 8

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, backup, disk-utility, data-recovery

My Time Machine backup disk is borked. Normally, I'd just reformat and re-run the backup, but that disk also has a folder of pictures separate from the Time Machine files that I need to recover.

The Seagate "FreeAgent" 1.5 TB external HD doesn't mount. DiskUtility reports "File system check exit code is 8." and suggests repairs. Repairs (via DiskUtility), of course, don't work, so Disk Utility tells me to "Backup as many files as possible, restore the disk ... [etc.]" I'd love to, and am happy to reformat, *if I can pull a single folder of pictures from the drive*.

My Google-fu is weak with this one. Some pages have suggested [`ddrescue`](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/), but that's a bit beyond my ken, and I only need one root folder recovered, not the entire backup drive.

OS X 10.10.3

Comment: The symptoms happened repeatably. Surprisingly, however, after leaving the drive plugged in (unmounted, as described) overnight (laptop slept, awoke), in the morning the drive was mounted, readable and thus far has returned to working without errors.  Weird.

Comment: Was your drive an SSD?

Comment: No, not an SSD.

Comment: Hi, I am in the same situation but the trick of waiting all night did not work :) Anyone has ideas on how to fix an external non-SSD drive that reports reports "File system check exit code is 8." ?